# how many ways can I reach Q from P?

Tags: graph-theory

without passing trough the same path again how many paths are from P to Q?

[image]

The answer is B) but I don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Question is indeed not clear. I think the answer is infinite and that answer is not listed...

Comment: You don't know how to solve what problem?

Comment: :D sorry let me edit it for the better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want know how many distinct paths are there from $P$ to $Q$ such that no backtracking is done.

Starting at $P$ (the top of the head of what looks like a teddy bear) we have $2$ choices (go left or right). At the ear we have $3$ choices (go around the ear clockwise, go around the ear counterclockwise, or not going into the ear at all). At the neck we have $2$ choices again. At either arm we have $3$ choices again. And at either leg we have $3$. We arrive at the... umm... point $Q$.

This gives $2\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 =108$.

Comment: I reverse engineered it too and came to what you came, but you didn't explain the details carefully, in my opinion. We have 3 choices at the ear because we may: 1. Choose not to travel on that loop (ear), or 2. Choose to travel on that loop (ear) clockwise, or 3. Choose to travel on the ear counterclockwise. Also, if we choose to travel on the ear we could do it only once. (I just saw the OP was edited, saying "without passing trough the same path again", which wasn't said earlier.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will clarify it, thanks!

Comment: very simple yet exelent observation I would see that the way you saw it if I would be a kid back in school but as an adult that left books for a long time is quite  different :D ... thanks